# Is there any formal mathematical analysis of democratic peace theory?

Tags: international-relations, democracy, political-theory

The democratic peace theory postulates that democracies are less likely to go to war, or at least less likely to go to war with other democracies. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democratic_peace_theory for more details.)

I have only seen this theory proposed as a verbal argument. Is there any attempt to formalize the argument using formal *mathematical* models?

That is, with a formal mathematical model of international relations and domestic political processes, what assumptions are needed to arrive at the conclusion that democracies are less likely to go to war (with each other)?

Comment: It is going to be difficult without definitions of "democracy" and "war".  Most countries have some form of voting, and they [rarely declare war](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/09636412.2012.734227).

Comment: @User65535 I understand people can differ significantly on these definitions. I am simply asking whether those who *advocate* for this theory have tried to come up with any formal justifications using any definition.

Comment: This question needs a lot more details to ensure that any answer will meet the requirements

Comment: @JoeW Sure, can you elaborate? Is the idea of "formal theory" not clear? I believe everything else is clearly defined.

Comment: What are you looking for that isn't covered by the wiki article? It goes into pretty good detail on the attempts using statistical analysis and the potential problems of the analysis. And of course the citations cover the research in even greater detail.

Comment: @eps "Formal model" requires a full-fledged mathematical model. "Verbal argument" is not formal. Most "verbal models" for moderately complex phenomenon are flawed. I'll clarify in the question momentarily.

Comment: @eps Okay, let me be even more straightforward. Given my knowledge of IR and political science, the probability that there is a formal model ever attempted is very low. I'm simply trying to see if I missed anything lying somewhere in the dark corners of academia.

Comment: What I am saying is I think we need a lot more details as it appears to be we need to go read a link to understand what you are asking.

Comment: yes, if you think statistics/statistical analysis aren't "formal models" you'll have to go into a lot more detail for us to understand what you are asking

Comment: Formal mathematical models are not the be-all-and-end-all of philosophical thought. Those who have tried to apply them to psychology and social theory (E.g., rational actor theory and game theory) have generally ended up with poor, unworkable theories predicated on a wide range of questionable assumptions. think you're after a red herring here...

Comment: @TedWrigley I agree with you. That said, we also know that human intuition is subject to various failures. Mathematical models are merely checks on logical consistencies. They are at best starting points of scientific research, so certainly not “be all and end alls”.

Comment: If there is, the mathematical sub-discipline at play would probably be "game theory". See, e.g., https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.01876.pdf and https://blogs.cornell.edu/info2040/2019/09/20/repeated-prisoners-dilemma-the-importance-of-game-theory-in-military-and-war/

Comment: @JLi "Mathematical models are merely checks on logical consistencies. " no not really, models are only as good as the assumptions they are based on. all kinds of models are complete nonsense and worth nothing or even worse than nothing, some are useful.

Comment: but more than that statistical analysis, which is the primary method you would use to test the theory you are interested in, are absolutely "math models" and is well covered in the wiki you linked.

Comment: @JLi I think a similar or related question could still fly here, but it would have to be adjusted to better fit the scope of this site, otherwise five people who did poorly in math class in high school and are still mad about it will close it as well (humor, partially). Sometimes SE sites will close questions that are simply too hard or require too much work to answer as seen by some group of users. It shouldn't be that way but it happens. Maybe start with something simpler then work your way up to more complex questions, cultivating a series of accepted answers and "establishing precedent"?

Comment: @uhoh Thanks for the sympathetic note. I entirely agree that this question is not suit for SE; it might be suited for certain academic IR theorists, but not otherwise. My question requires too much background, and it is simply isn't worth it trying to go over the entire background, I think. Specifically, this would involve a discussion about what I mean by formal modeling, what formal modeling achieves (or not), etc. Further, I'm fairly sure that the answer to my question is "no", but only someone fully confident in her knowledge of IR can really give such an answer.

Comment: @uhoh There is no answer in the link I posted. The difficulty is in what counts as "formal mathematical modeling", and I think it is really not worth explaining further.

Comment: @JLi if you have plenty of time and/or motivation you can always slowly cultivate an interest niche in a site through many *incremental* questions and postings in related sites, sort-of a community-building effort.  (and yes, but if it *looks like it might be an answer* then folks will do what they did)

Comment: @uhoh I agree. I'm not 100% sure I'm able to do much of helpful "community building" either. My knowledge of IR theory is mostly focused in certain esoteric directions --- this is, unfortunately, how academia is organized these days, each person having a very specific niche. As a consequence, my questions, and also my answers to questions, often only make sense to a very specialized audience.